# Applescript: How to open a random file from a specified volume? (.dmg location)

Tags: applescript

Ok so if I want to open a random file from a **folder** on my Mac, I can use the following script succesfully:

```
tell application "Finder"

    open some file of (folder ("⁨⁨Users:chris:Desktop:photoAlbum") of startup disk)
end tell
```

However, I'm not sure what syntax to use when I want to open a random file from a **volume/disk image** I have mounted. The volume is located at */Users/chris/Downloads/photoAlbum.dmg* but the following is not successful:

```
tell application "Finder"

    open some file of (folder ("⁨⁨Users:chris:Downloads:photoAlbum.dmg") of startup disk)
end tell
```

What script should I be using instead to do the latter?

Comment: The volume is not mounted at `/users` it is mounted at `/Volumes/[volume name]/the/rest/of/your/path` **but** only once it is actually mounted. Before that you cannot see inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the disk in question is **not** already mounted, then:

```
tell application id "com.apple.Finder"
    set downloads to the path to the downloads folder
    set _files to a reference to files in downloads
    set _disks to the name of every disk
    set _dmgs to the name of the _files whose name extension = "dmg"
    set _selection to choose from list of _dmgs with multiple selections allowed

    open (the _files whose name is in the _selection)
    set _volumes to a reference to (the disks whose name is not in _disks)

    repeat until (_volumes exists)
        delay 1
    end repeat

    open some file in some disk of (get _volumes)
end tell
```

Comment: @user3439894 For scripts, I indent with using hard tabs that have a width of 8 spaces (_StackExchange_ converts these to spaces, which is a bit annoying).  I indent config files with 2 spaces; and serialised nested output with 4 spaces.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`  Admittedly, the hard tabs can be problematic in a shell, but I set my shells up to cater for it.

Comment: @user3439894 I just reduced it to 4 spaces, since it's the more conventional indentation.